# JavaScript trigger beforeunload only when closing

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am using the following code to catch the moment when a user tries to close or back a page:

```
 window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
   var confirmationMessage = "Are you sure?";
   (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; 
   return confirmationMessage;                            
 });
```

However, I have a few buttons and links on the page that also triggers the event when clicked, I wonder if there is any way to avoid listening the event when clicking anchor tags and buttons but only when closing or back?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could this give a hint? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227383/how-to-detect-browser-window-tab-close-event

Comment: You could declare a global `var shouldConfirm = true;` and then on click of any `<a>` or `<button>` set it to false. Only show confirmation if `shouldConfirm == true` ?

Comment: You could a `class` or some other identifier to these links and buttons. On your `beforeunload` event, check if this has been triggered by an element with the identifier, if it is, don't show the confirmation message.

Comment: basically I would need kind of a not(button and anchor tag) but I'm not sure if that possible @kei