# Tracking mobile browser exit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tag-manager

I'm looking to set up an A/B test which is supposed to measure the amount of times someone closes the browser window on a mobile phone.

Is this even possible? My research basically tell me it's not.

Comment: well it isn't possible to track when user closes browser. what you can do is use a beacon which executes even if browser gets closed and maybe track time difference or something. but beacon is not supported throughout right now.

Comment: also possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227383/how-to-detect-browser-window-tab-close-event

Comment: A comprehensive article on the topic: https://www.igvita.com/2015/11/20/dont-lose-user-and-app-state-use-page-visibility/

Answer (score 0):

No but you can use [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) to determine the current visibility state of the page.

[Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=visibilit) is not bad.