# unload function listening to both refresh and close

Tags: javascript, onunload

I am trying to catch a event i.e. window close. So i used unload, but it catches both refresh and close. So my action gets triggered for both. Is there a way to catch only close event?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Detect Browser Window /Tab Close Event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227383/how-to-detect-browser-window-tab-close-event)

Comment: But no solution there.

Comment: 2nd answer says it : "You can't detect it with javascript." So you can't.