# Some way to detect close tab/browser for all browsers?

Tags: javascript, events, browser-close

There are some way of detecting a close event from tab/browser without close when i click in other links in page or forms and valid for all browser, i tested "beforeunload" and other replies about this topic here and not working, i am testing in Firefox and Chrome
This is not working :

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
    var message = 'Important: Please click on \'Save\' button to leave this page.';
    if (typeof event == 'undefined') {
        event = window.event;
    }
    if (event) {
        event.returnValue = message;
    }
    return message;
};
```

Same when i close the tab or the browser is doing nothing; but yes when i click a link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to detect browser close event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853142/trying-to-detect-browser-close-event)

Comment: Note: a window/tab close event cannot be prevented "silently" the same way than other events. At maximum, you can show an alert asking the user if he wants to leave or not

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Detect Browser Window /Tab Close Event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227383/how-to-detect-browser-window-tab-close-event)